# How to take last three month date range in ES query irrespective of present month?

Tags: elasticsearch

```json
GET index_name/_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "time": {
              "gte": "now-3M/M",
              "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "_id:*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How should we give "gte" specific to 3M/M, getting error as - failed to parse date field [3M/M] with format?

Comment: I've just tried this exact range query and it worked like a charm. Are you sure your index contains correct mappings? If so, what version do you use?

Comment: Same as @EvaldasBuinauskas, works perfectly on the `v 7.10.2`. Which `ES` version are you using ?

Could you perhaps have a type on the field `time` to be something else than `date`.
To check the mapping `GET /index_name/_mapping`

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas and https://stackoverflow.com/users/4534923/paulo ---- this query is not working for me, using ES 7.6.1 - getting below error - "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parse_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to parse date field [3M/M] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]: [failed to parse date field [3M/M] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]]"
      }

Comment: Want to automate this gte  as 3M/M that should treat as 1oct2021 to 31dec2021 if working in Jan, if in feb this should be treated as 1nov2021 to 31jan2022 and lte should be now.  time is in the format "type" : "date" ,,,,,,,, gte takes this format manually - 2021-10-01T00:00:00Z ,